# How to compact an @id?

Tags: rdf, owl, json-ld, rdfs, linked-data

Is it possbile to compact iris in @id via the context?
I didn't found a solution for that, without using @base.

```
    {
      "@context":  {
        "MaxMustermann": "http://example.org/MaxMustermann",
        "name": "https://schema.org/name"
      },
      "@id": "MaxMustermann",
      "name": "Max Mustermann"
    }
```

best regards

Answer (score 0):

You could write your @id as a [compact IRI](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#compact-iris) using a notation consisting of a prefix and a suffix. Prefixes are defined inside your `@context`.
Have a look at this input:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "ex": "http://example.org/",
    "foaf": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
  },
  "@type": "foaf:Person",
  "@id":"ex:MaxMustermann"
}
```

This translates to this expanded definition:

```
[
  {
    "@id": "http://example.org/MaxMustermann",
    "@type": [
      "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person"
    ]
  }
]
```

You can also view this example on the [JSON-LD playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-expanded&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22ex%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F%22%2C%22foaf%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%22%7D%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22foaf%3APerson%22%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3AMaxMustermann%22%7D&context=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22ex%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fexample%2F%22%7D%7D).
As you can see, the prefix `ex` is used to abbreviate the namespace of the `@id` IRI. Same goes for `@type` where the prefix `foaf` is used.
Is this what you're looking for?